# How can I display icons inside a elements but hide the text for search engines?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the ElegantIcons font to add social icons to a website. As you can see in the code below the icon is applied to the anchor `<a>` `::before` pseudo-element. Unlike FontAwesome that can use an `<i>` tag and a `class name` this font-face has to be applied by using `::before` and `content: "\xxx"` where xxx is the code of the icon

[image]

I would like to hide the text of the link and only keep that for search engines or text browsers. I tried wrapping the name of the text inside a separate `<span>` tag and hide that with the `screen-readers` class. I'm not sure if this it is the right approach. I would like to have your suggestion.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
  src: url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.eot'),
  url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.screen-readers {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #007cba;
}

.social {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.social > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: .1875em;

}

.social > li + li {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.icon-facebook::before {
  content: "\e093";
  font-family: ElegantIcons;
}

.icon-twitter::before {
  content: "\e094";
  font-family: ElegantIcons;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="elegant-icons.css">
  <title>Elegant Icons</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="social">
      <li>
        <a class="icon-facebook" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="screen-readers">Facebook</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="icon-twitter" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span class="screen-readers">Twitter</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  font-size: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
  src: url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.eot'),
  url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/elegant/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.screen-readers {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #007cba;
}

.social {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.social > li > a {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: .1875em;

}

.social > li + li {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.icon-facebook::before {
  content: "\e093";
  font-family: ElegantIcons;
}

.icon-twitter::before {
  content: "\e094";
  font-family: ElegantIcons;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="elegant-icons.css">
  <title>Elegant Icons</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="social">
      <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Facebook">
          <span class="icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="screen-readers">Facebook</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Twitter">
        <span class="icon-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="screen-readers">Twitter</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have updated my answer using your original code snippet.

- A separate span for the icon and put aria-hidden="true" on it so screen readers won't try to read it.
- Keep the 'screen-readers' class for search engines.
- Add aria-label="Facebook" on the link. This should override what is in the link, but I'm not sure all screen readers implement it.

Comment: The first span with `aria-hidden="true"` displays the text "Facebook" which I don't need. I only want to see the icons, and the text only for screen readers.

Comment: I posted an image at the top of my post, that's the final result I want, just the icons.